# R package for implementing linear mixed model with multivariate t distribution

Tags: r, mixed-model

I've been reading the 2001 paper by Pinheiro et al. "Efficient Algorithms for Robust Estimation in Linear Mixed-Effects Models Using the Multivariate t Distribution" and I was wondering whether there are R packages to implement this type of linear mixed model since I am not aware of being able to fit this model in either lme4 or nlme. I've searched for packages but have not found any so far so any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [brms package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_overview.pdf) with the option `familiy = student()`, but this is a Bayesian model.

Comment: Also check out `robustlmm` and the `heavy` packages. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustlmm/vignettes/rlmer.pdf

Comment: @ErikRuzek Had been looking at those ones as well - good recommendations